# Expressing uncertainty while making a statement (I think...)

Tags: грамматика, перевод

What's an acceptable way to make a statement while at the same time expressing some uncertainty about that statement / giving an indication that's it's only your opinion? i.e. the Russian equivalent of adding an extra "I think" to an independent clause.

For example, take this (admittedly clunky) English sentence:

> I'm talking about something that I think she already knows.

My ideas for how to translate into Russian would be something like:

1. Я говорю о том, которое по-моему она уже знает.
2. Я говорю о том, которое я думаю что она уже знает.
3. Я говорю о том, которое она уже знает ли.

But none of them seem quite correct. What would be the correct  way of adding "I think" to that second clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я говорю о том, <strike>которое</strike> **ЧТО** она **,** по-моему **,** уже знает.
>
> Я говорю о том, <strike>которое</strike> **ЧТО** она **,** я думаю **,**  уже знает.

ОR

> Я говорю о том, что она, (как) мне кажется, уже знает

Stylistically such insert phrase sounds better after **она**.

Correct conjunction here is not **которое**, but **что**.

**Которое** would be correct if the main clause explicitly contained an object in Neuter gender and not just pointed at it with the demonstrative pronoun **то**, e.g.

> Я говорю о том **деле**, **которое** она, (как) мне кажется, уже *видела*

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to the answers provided yet another form quite often used colloquially - it's ["сдаётся мне"](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/159923/%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F), like in:

> Я говорю о том, о чём, **сдаётся мне**, она уже знает.

Also colloquial:

> Я говорю о том, о чём, **как по мне**, она уже знает.

More bookish but actually also used:

> Я говорю о том, о чём, **думается мне**, она уже знает.

Also bookish and quite lengthy but also quite used:

> Я говорю о том, о чём, **насколько я могу судить**, она уже знает.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm talking about something that I think she already knows" could be translated like this:

> Я говорю о том, о чём она, **кажется**, уже знает.
>
> Я говорю о том, о чём она, **по-моему**, уже знает.
>
> Я говорю о том, о чём она, **как мне кажется**, уже знает.
>
> Я говорю о том, о чём она уже, **по всей видимости**, знает.

By the way, "Я говорю о том, о чём..." is the same as "Я говорю о том, что..." in this sentence because we can say *знать что-то* and *знать о чём-то.*

All these phrases in bold can be used at end of the sentence, that is after "знает", after "уже", or in the position I have used them in.

Comment: This set of phrases in bold could be widened with two words: *наверно* which expresses uncertainty and similar *наверняка* which is more certain.